# How to sum columns without using Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reformat a report so it can feed into my system like below:

```
wbOutput.Sheets(1).Range("B" & O_lrow + 1 & ":B" & O_lrow + lRow).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("F1:F" & lRow).Value
```

One issue I encounter is column F needs to be the sum of two source column and below doesn't work:

```
wbOutput.Sheets(1).Range("F" & O_lrow + 1 & ":F" & O_lrow + lRow).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("N1:N" & lRow).Value + wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("O1:O" & lRow).Value
```

I am trying to avoid using loop as there are many rows and I don't want the marco slow down too much.

Is there any simple way to achieve this without using a loop?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 wbOutput.Sheets(1).Range("F" & O_lrow + 1 & ":F" & O_lrow + lRow).Value = _ 
             wbSource.Sheets(1).Evaluate("N1:N" & lRow & " + O1:O" & lRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way, using the `Application.Sum` function:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SumTest()

    Dim SumA As Range
    Dim SumB As Range

    With wbSource.Sheets(1)
        Set SumA = .Range("N1:N" & lRow)
        Set SumB = .Range("O1:O" & lRow)
    End With

    wbOutput.Sheets(1).Range("F" & O_lrow + 1 & ":F" & O_lrow + lRow) = Application.Sum(SumA, SumB)

End Sub
```

Comment: this sums the whole column for me and so all rows in output is having the same value, which is not exactly what i am looking for. thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You already have two good answers, just want to add my 2 cents here...

If you have lots of data, you should consider using arrays, and one way of doing what you are trying to achieve can be the below, please see comments for further details:

```vb
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet: Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets(1) 'allocate the output worksheet to a variable
Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1) 'allocate the source worksheet to a variable

Dim arrSource As Variant
Dim arrOutput() As Variant 'Could change this to match your expected data type output
Dim R As Long, C As Long
arrSource = wsSource.Range("N1:O" & lRow) 'Get the source data into an array
ReDim arrOutput(1 To UBound(arrSource), 1 To 1) 'set the size of the output
For R = 1 To UBound(arrSource)
    For C = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2)
        arrOutput(R, 1) = arrSource(R, 1) + arrSource(R, 2) 'make your calculations here
    Next C
Next R

wsOutput.Range("F" & O_lrow + 1 & ":F" & O_lrow + lRow) = arrOutput 'spit it back to the sheet once is done
```

Comment: this is actually in my mine but it uses loop which i am trying to avoid in my macro.